# Архитектурный подход для сохранения данных приложения

Tags: java, архитектура, шаблоны-проектирования, хранение-данных

Доброго времени суток.

**Задача:** имеется приложение под Desctop и Android. Нужно определить архитектурный подход для сохранения данных приложения в постоянную память с учетом следующих особенностей:

1. Часть полей объекта некоторого типа являются частью его внутренней реализации и должны быть полностью скрыты от клиентского кода, при этом значение этих полей также должны быть сохранены.
2. Место и способ хранения объектов могут меняться и добавляться походу портирования и развития приложения (так объекты могут сохраняться в json или xml файлы хранящиеся на машине пользователя с помощью SAX или DOM парсера [Desctop версия]; сохраняться в реляционную[SQLite, HyperSql, MySql] подключаясь через JDBC или какую-нибудь ORM; сохраняться на сервер).
3. Объекты некоторых типов неизменяемые.

**Какие подходы я пробовал:**

1. Реализовать методы save() и load() у каждого класса, объекты которого нужно сохранять. Если нужно сохранять объект несколькими способами, то для каждого способа делаем свою пару  методов (например saveToJson(), loadToJson() и т.д.)

   *Плюсы на мой взгляд*: поля для внутренней реализации остаются полностью скрытыми от клиентского кода и при этом мы спокойно можем их сохранять/загружать.

   *Минусы на мой взгляд*: как мне кажется, нарушается принцип единой ответственности. И второй минус - этот подход нельзя применить к неизменяемым полям (и как следствие - неизменяемым объектам), поскольку их инициализация может проводиться только в момент вызова конструктора (хотелось бы сохранять все объекты приложения единообразным способом).
2. Использования несколько измененного паттерна Memento (для сохранения объекта получаем его объект-хранитель и сохраняем его. В отличие от классической реализации паттерна, для восстановления объекта-создателя будем передавать объект-хранитель в конструктор, а не в специальный метод).

   *Плюсы на мой взгляд*: читать/писать значение скрытых полей непосредственно у самих объектов - неполучится. Второй плюс - код отвечающий за сохранение можно вынести в отдельный модуль и поместить в отдельном пакете.

   *Минусы на мой взгляд*: объект-хранитель должен открыть доступ к своему состоянию не только для объекта-создателя, но и для объектов, которые будут заниматься его сохранением. Получается, что через объект-хранитель, объект-создатель косвенно раскрывает все свое состояние.
3. В отдельном модуле объявить DAO интерфейс для каждого типа объектов, которые требуется сохранять. Если у какого-то класса есть поля, доступ к которым он не хотел бы предоставлять клиентскому коду, то DAO интерфейс реализуется в виде вложенного класса.

   *Плюсы на мой взгляд*: благодаря вложенным класса поля для внутренней реализации остаются полностью скрытыми от клиентского кода.

   *Минусы на мой взгляд*: из-за вложенных классов код отвечающий за сохранение не может быть целиком выделен в отдельный модуль и размещен  в отдельном пакете. Таким образом код отвечающий за сохранение растаскивается по модулям и пакетам.

**Вопрос:**
Как принято решать похожие задачи? Стоит ли выбрать один из трех вариантов, которые я рассмотрел и если да, то почему? Если я, по вашему мнению, ошибся в описании плюсов и минусов некоторых рассмотренных мной решений - пожалуйста укажите на это.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В начале я попытался доработать идею с методами save() и load(). Решил создать некоторые обобщенные интерфейсы Saver и Loader, через которые можно будет единообразно работать с JSON, XML и SQL. Сохраняемые объекты должны иметь метод save(Saver saver) и конструктор с параметром Loader (не метод load(Loader loader), а именно конструктор, чтобы была возможность загружать final поля). Чтобы интерфейсы не требовали раскрытия скрываемых полей сохраняемых объектов и могли применяться для работы с любым типом объектов, а также могли работать с XML, JSON и SQL, необходимо чтобы они сразу были рассчитаны для работы с иерархическими структурами данных. Я решил сделать что-то вроде:

```
public interface Saver {
    public Saver beginSection() throws Exception;
    public Saver endSection() throws Exception;
    public Saver meta(MetaData meta) throws Exception;
    public Saver value(String key, int value) throws Exception;
    public Saver value(String key, boolean value) throws Exception;
    //... Перегрузки метода value() для других типов данных
    public void save() throws Exception;
    public void close() throws Exception;
}
```

и для загрузки

```
public interface Loader {
    public void beginSection() throws Exception;
    public void endSection() throws Exception;
    public MeatData nextMeta() throws Exception;
    public boolean hasNextTokenInSection() throws Exception;
    public int getInt(String key) throws Exception;
    public boolean getBoolean(String key) throws Exception;
    //... Другие методы nextXXX() для других типов данных.
    public void close() throws Exception;
}
```

Но попытка подобрать обобщенный интерфейс оборачивалась либо крайне скудным на функционал интерфейсом не позволяющим использовать особенности формата хранения данных (XML, JSON, таблицы реляционных БД), либо становился крайне противоречивым и раздутым. К тому же подобрать обобщенный интерфейс для всех способов работы с данными просто не получится (я не представляю, КАК должен выглядеть интерфейс, для работы и с ORM, и с XML, и с JSON). вывод - попытка подобрать обобщенный интерфейс для всего на свете - идея изначально обреченная на провал. С каждым форматом хранения данных нужно работать специфичным для него способом.

Как итог, я остановился на втором способе решения поставленной задачи (паттерн Memento), поскольку он позволяет работать с каждым форматом хранения данных специфичным для него способом (не смешивая все в кашу), а также полностью оделить код отвечающий за сохранение, от кода бизнес логики, хотя и ценой ослабления инкапсуляции.